# Which adapter do I need to mount a vintage Marexar-CX Lens to Nikon D3100?

Tags: nikon, old-lenses, lens-mount, lens-adapter, marexar

I have purchased a vintage MAREXAR-CX Zoom, MACRO lens, Multi-Coated 1:4.5-4.8  F=80-250mm 58 No 90686.

It says is a Minolta fitting lens, made in Japan. I would like to try it out with my Nikon D3100 but I don't know which is the right adapter for it.

In the description it says it is a Minolta fitting but on the lens cap it has PK on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're going to have to figure out first whether the lens is fitted for a Minolta MC/MD mount or a Pentak K. If you can find a spot on the lens where that information is actually engraved, it would help a lot. Often with third-party lenses it will just be a two-letter identifier; in this case, "MC", "MD", "PK" or possibly just "K". If you can't find it engraved, you might have to get some help identifying the mount; either a camera or a lens back cap in the appropriate mount in good condition will let you know.

In either case, you need an adapter with an optical element to allow infinity focus. That's usually in the form of a built-in 1.4X teleconverter, so your lens will wind up being a 112-350mm f/6.3-6.7 with the adapter. If it's a Minolta mount lens, you'll need a [Minolta MC/MD to Nikon F adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003EDYIM6). If a Pentax, you'll need a [Pentax K to Nikon F adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003Y31A2W).

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, was really helpful. I followed your advice and i am thinking of purchasing http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Minolta-MC-MD-mount-lens-to-Nikon-F-mount-adapter-D90-D300S-D3100-D5100-D7000-/260894480956?pt=UK_Photography_CameraLenses_Lens_caps_hoods_adaptors_ET&hash=item3cbe85da3c#ht_2180wt_1156

Comment: iahve tried the tube extensions but they didnt work, I took several photos but didnt come out. i am thinking of buying a M42 vintage lens and give that a try as i can not afford the proper lens.Any suggestions?

Comment: @Donmagicjuan No matter what old, manual-focus lens you use, you're going to be completely responsible for getting the exposure right; the camera won't do it for you. If you want auto-anything, you'll need to get a lens designed for the Nikon F mount. AI lenses will meter properly; AI-S lenses will let the body control the aperture.

Comment: Some Pentax K rear caps fit a few other bayonet mounts - some of mine fit Sony E for some reason :)